# Why not wrap content within `<noscript>`?

Tags: html, noscript

It seems common to use the following HTML structure to accommodate
users who have enabled/disable javascript:

```
 <html>
     <style>
         div.body { display:none; }
         .body > ... { ... }
     </style> 
     <script>
         document.onload( function() {
             javascript(CONTENT => div.body);
         });
     </script> 
     <noscript>
         <style>
             body > :not(noscript) {
                 display:none;
             }
         </style>
     </noscript>
 <body>
     <div class="body"> 
     </div>
     <noscript class="body">
         CONTENT
     </noscript>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The mechanism uses a `<div>`; whose `display` attribute, initially set
to `none`, is subsequently set to `block|grid|etc.` and populated with
`CONTENT` once the page is loaded; alongside a `<noscript>`; which is
pre-populated with `CONTENT`.

No one seems to suggest simply popping the `CONTENT` within
`<noscript>` into the `<body>` when javascript is available as follows
:

```
 <html>
     <style>
         .body { ... }
         .body > ... { ... }
     </style> 
     <script>
         document.onload( function() {
             let noscript = document.querySelector("noscript");
             noscript.outerHTML = noscript.innerHTML;
         });
     </script> 
     <noscript>
         <style>
             body > noscript {
                 display:content;
             }
         </style>
     </noscript>
 <body>
     <noscript>
         CONTENT
     </noscript>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here the `CONTENT` within `noscript` is displayed by default and if
there is javascript the tag is simply dropped; the specification
states the content of noscript should be parsable and that the parsed
result be readily assignable as `noscript.outerHTML`.

The first method requires one to repeat ones `CONTENT` in both the
`noscript` and wrapped into the javascript that populates the `div`;
this isn't especially DRY. I can't see that populating a page through
javascript calls is any faster then assigning `ELEMENT.outerHTML`; if
this is not true let me know.  The second method relies upona bit of
CSS trickery. Finally both methods seem subject to flicker.

The only reasons I can think of for not using the latter structure are
:

- SEO; I can't see how though e.g. you only have to scan `CONTENT` once, it sn't repeated, it isn't bundled between javascript, better
  aria/a11y support.
- Frontend framework e.g. they all rely on the first structure
- historic reasons e.g. setting `noscript.outerHTML` breaks events or something ut they are broken under the spec anyhow, jQuery.unwrap
  being a "recent" development, browser woes.